# How to import module from url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a vuejs npm package in my application. For some reasons, I need to use with cdn url directly so let's suppose this is the cdn lib `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/my-package@1.1.0/dist/my-package.umd.min.js`. Now I don't know how to use that in vue application.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316864/is-it-possible-to-include-a-vue-js-component-from-a-url

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried but no success. The thing in which I stucked is how to make that component available in my vue application

Comment: You can install the package using that url using `npm i https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/my-package@1.1.0/dist/my-package.umd.min.js`. Or does it have to be dynamically loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem perfectly and I will answer about your question.

In vue project,  there is html page that shows to clients finally.

This is original html page, so it has header and body tag.

In header tag, as you can see, there are script and link .

Then you want to use other urls, you can input this url using `<script>` tag.

This is sample below.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/my-package@1.1.0/dist/my-package.umd.min.js"></script>
```